# Stuck on very easy Excel Issue

Tags: excel, math, formulas

I have one huge dataset in one column and one smaller one in other column. 
But both are lists and not numbers

I want to check if text in smaller one is part of larger one
what formula to use?

so i want to see for. e.g.  if B1 belongs to A1:A5000 but i want to see this for all B1:B1000

Comment: What do you mean by "lists"? Each cell contains a comma separated values list?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in C1:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1,A:A,0))
```

And copy down.

It will put `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on whether it is found in Column A or not.